# Android dialog called as intent is not showing the background screen. It is showing black backgroud

Tags: android, android-intent

I am calling a dialog as Intent from the main application screen.
Now when the dialog opens, it is showing black backgroud.

I want to show the main application in the backgroud even thought the dialog is opened as intent.

Comment: Show how you are doing it, add some code

Answer (score 0):

opening a new intent means that your application will call atleast onPause, more likely even onStop. 
if you want to do what you're doing - even if thats not androids way things should be done - then you have to overwrite the handling of your "background" activitys onStop so that it's not  removeing the activity from view.
however, i've never done that and i'm not even sure if its possible. 
it dosn't seem to be a good idea anyway.

why dont you look around how other apps - few of them for sure haveing the same problem - work around it and still got a nice looking UI?

oh btw, you know that you don't have to open a dialog as a new itent for showing it - do you?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to apply the `Dialog` theme to the activity that implements your dialog:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme